# SharePoint images aren't rendering in PowerBI

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, powerbi, dashboard

I have a PowerBI dashboard that uses an image library saved in SharePoint. The images render for me but not for the users (some are within my organisation (local teams), others outside - i.e. the client). Has anyone ever had this problem and if so what's the fix? Is there a different method of storing and retrieving images? Would GCP be an option?

Many thanks!

Saved all of the images in SharePoint and linked the folder using PowerQuery

Comment: What does the rendering failure look like? Have you got screenshots? It would also be good to try to load F12 devtools and see if there are any console errors and post them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Do these report consumers have permission to the folder?
I assume not because you said that there are some external users.

Remember that Power BI Service needs to be able to access your SharePoint List.

You could try to force the SharePoint connection through an On-premise gateway even though technically that is unnecessary.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)